# Which of these three options would be fastest to populate my DB table?

Tags: php, mysql, curl, xmlreader

I have a (huge: 6.4 million rows) database table with three columns as follows:

```
URL     Title      Description
```

Right now only the URL column is populated, with various urls from around the web. I have to add a title and meta description to the url in each row. There are three ways I see I can do this:

Option 1: Use php and CURL to go to each url and grab the title and meta:description. (Even with using options 2 or 3 I'll have to do this for at least part of the urls).

Option 2: I have a DMOZ xml file which has several million elements which look like this:

```
    <ExternalPage about="http://animation.about.com/">
       <d:Title>About.com: Animation Guide</d:Title>
       <d:Description>Keep up with developments in online animation for all skill levels.     Download tools, and seek inspiration from online work.</d:Description>
       <topic>Top/Arts/Animation</topic>
    </ExternalPage>
    <ExternalPage about="http://www.toonhound.com/">
       <d:Title>Toonhound</d:Title>
       <d:Description>British cartoon, animation and comic strip creations - links, reviews  and news from the UK.</d:Description>
       <topic>Top/Arts/Animation</topic>
    </ExternalPage>
```

etc.

I can use xmlreader to compare the url in every ExternalPage-about to see if it matches one of the 6.4 million urls in my table, and if it does, add the title and description.

Option 3: I can write all the above dmoz data into a separate database table (again using xmlreader), which will also take time, and then somehow use JOINs and SELECTs on the two tables to get the information I need.

Would option 2 or 3 be quicker for those urls than just using option 1 for all the urls? If yes, which of the two options would be faster?

Comment: Use `XMLReader` and `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` clause in `INSERT` statements. And LOOP it till the end of XML file.

Comment: @DoSparKot thanks. Just so I'm clear, you're advocating option 2 as the fastest?

Comment: "Use php and CURL to go to each url and grab the title and meta:description. (Even with using options 2 or 3 I'll have to do this for at least part of the url's)." <- *That will be the bottleneck. Remember, 97/3.* Options 2 and 3 have the same complexity *if using indexes correctly*, but Option 3 can reduce round-tripping. Use transactions in both cases. Option 1 isn't even comparable - it doesn't save/update anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "Faster" means less time to update your URL table, then option 3 seems to be the best option.

You can populate another table with records from XML and then using JOIN to update your main table.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a script, you will run it only once.. It doesn't matter if it is not very fast.
By the way 6 million rows are not too huge, it will take minutes on any decent computer.

CURL solution is not an option at all! do you know how long will it take to fetch 6 million URLS?!!

Insert the XML into database, and do queries as you like.

**EDIT**: To capture millions of URLs (it might take weeks to finish!):

1. Get a [cheap vps](http://www.lowendbox.com/) server (faster connection than your home computer).
2. Export urls to text file.
3. use wget to download each URL (don't forget to use multiple wget processes).

Comment: thanks for your answer. So you're saying option 3 is the best? Also re CURL, I don't really have a choice, as there will still be several million urls which the dmoz file doesn't have data for, and I need the data... :-(

Comment: is there a reason to use wget rather than curl?

Comment: wget is already out there, you don't need to write code again. I am sure also it will be more efficient.